# HBase masters are going down after enabling Ranger plugin

Tags: hadoop, hbase, ambari, apache-ranger

I have a 3 node Distributed Hbase cluster of version 2.0.2 and its working properly. After I Installed apache ranger From Same Ambari & I just Enabled the Hbase plugin and then I restarted the HBase Immediately Both HBase masters are getting down with Below logs.

```
 ERROR [Thread-16] master.HMaster: ***** ABORTING master ,16000,1585061451214: The coprocessor org.apache.ranger.authorization.hbase.RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor threw java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /run/hbase/.cache/JNA/temp/jna2781046120401699711.tmp: /run/hbase/.cache/JNA/temp/jna2781046120401699711.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object *****


ERROR [Thread-16] master.HMaster: Failed to become active master
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.startProcedureExecutor(HMaster.java:1405)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.startServiceThreads(HMaster.java:1310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishActiveMasterInitialization(HMaster.java:930)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.startActiveMasterManager(HMaster.java:2234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.lambda$run$0(HMaster.java:570)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I Disable the Plugin and everything is working fine

Comment: can anybody assist here

Answer (score 0):

We were experiencing a similar issue with a near identical stack trace to yours. Like you, everything worked only if the plugin was disabled.

For us it turns out that the reason was that the `/run` mount had a `noexec` flag, which prevented tmp files from being executed within it. The solution was to remount `/run` on the Hbase master nodes using:

`sudo mount -o remount,exec /run`

After this we restarted the HBase services and everything was working again.

Note that this modified mount will not be saved after a restart of the machine. For it to persist you may need to use something like `fstab`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. below is my fstab  file

Comment: UUID=7a458138-4b3b-4eb1-a43a-0eaca8b56ea8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=346b7044-c404-4356-be22-33004c77a56e none            swap    sw              0       0

Comment: If I remount using above command. will it affect to file system?

Comment: I can't comment on your fstab entries as I'm not really familiar with them. As for running ```sudo mount -o remount,exec /run``` I think you should be able to run that safely, but again I'm not hugely familiar. All I know is that it fixed our problem.